# Analytic\approximate solution for nonlinear ODE

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve:

```
        ([y]'[x])^2 + y''[x]* y[x] + y[x] = 0 و y (0) = 1; y' (0) = 0
```

Is it possible to get exact or approximate or numerical solution on x in [0,1]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Approximate solution:

```
 $Version
 (*"13.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"*)
```

**Method 1:**

```
 solA = AsymptoticDSolveValue[{y'[x]^2 + y''[x]*y[x] + y[x] == 0, 
 y[0] == 1, y' [0] == 0}, y[x], {x, 0, 20}]
 
 (*1 - x^2/2 - x^4/12 - (7 x^6)/180 - x^8/45 - (457 x^10)/32400 - 
 (40859 x^12)/4276800 - (452 x^14)/66825 - (1269019 x^16)/256608000 - (
  145468123 x^18)/39261024000 - (8679629 x^20)/3067267500*) 

 Plot[{solA, Evaluate@D[solA, x]}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> {"y[x]", "y'[x]"}]
```

**Method 2:**

I borrowed the code from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211873/finding-ode-series-solution-coefficients).

```
ClearAll["`*"]; Remove["`*"]

y[x_] = Sum[a[s] x^s, {s, 0, 20}] + O[x]^21;
le = LogicalExpand[y'[x]^2 + y''[x]*y[x] + y[x] == 0];
sol1 = Solve[le, Table[a[s], {s, 2, 20}]];
yy[x_] = Normal[y[x] /. First@sol1];
sol2 = Solve[{yy[0] == 1, yy'[0] == 0}, {a[0], a[1]}];
wle[x_] = yy[x] /. First@sol2

(*1 - x^2/2 - x^4/12 - (7 x^6)/180 - x^8/45 - (457 x^10)/32400 - 
 (40859 x^12)/4276800 - (452 x^14)/66825 - (1269019 x^16)/256608000 - (
  145468123 x^18)/39261024000 - (8679629 x^20)/3067267500*)
```

Numerical solution:

```
 solB = NDSolveValue[{y'[x]^2 + y''[x]*y[x] + y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1, 
 y' [0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 1}]
 Plot[{solB[x], solB'[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> {"y[x]", "y'[x]"}]

 Table[{x, solB[x]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.05}]

 (*{{0., 1.}, {0.05, 0.998749}, {0.1, 0.994991}, {0.15, 
 0.988707}, {0.2, 0.979864}, {0.25, 0.968414}, {0.3, 0.954295}, {0.35, 
 0.937422}, {0.4, 0.917691}, {0.45, 0.894967}, {0.5, 0.86908}, 
 {0.55,0.839817}, {0.6, 0.806899}, {0.65, 0.769965}, {0.7, 
 0.728532}, {0.75, 0.681932}, {0.8, 0.629204}, {0.85, 
 0.568876}, {0.9, 0.498499}, {0.95, 0.413397}, {1., 0.302054}}*)
```

Exact solution:

```
 DSolveValue[{y'[x]^2 + y''[x]*y[x] + y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, y[x], x]

 (*Can't find any*)
```

Using [Maple 2021](https://www.maplesoft.com/products/Maple/students/), can find 2 solutions expressed by **RootOf** function.

[image]

Solving integrals and converting to Mathematica **implicit** 2 solutions and plot:

```
ContourPlot[{Sqrt[6] Gamma[2/3] Gamma[5/6]/(2 Sqrt[Pi]) - 
Sqrt[6]/4 y^2 Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 2/3, 5/3, y^3] == x, -Sqrt[6] Gamma[2/3] Gamma[5/6]/(2 Sqrt[Pi]) + 
Sqrt[6]/4 y^2 Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 2/3, 5/3, y^3] == x},
{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2.5, 1.2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Mariusz, I used version 11, I think the above function not available?

Comment: @user62716. You can use Mathematica for **free** and execute my code with some time limitation on Wolfram Cloud. https://develop.wolframcloud.com  You must only sign in.

Comment: manythanks, for numerical solution can I get  values say in a table?

Comment: Many thanks and my best regards

Comment: @user62716 If you want, instead of `AsymptoticDSolveValue` you can expand the differential equation using `Series` and then `DSolve` the expanded version of the D.E.

Comment: Dear kcr, I don't know?

Comment: @user62716 .I updated my answer.

Comment: Many thanks for your great works!!!

Comment: @user62716 I meant what is presented as **Method 2** in this answer. Great answer btw!!!

Comment: many thanks kcr

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way to coax `DSolve` from the general solution to the IVP:

```
ode = (y'[x])^2 + y''[x]*y[x] + y[x] == 0;
ics = {y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0};
gensol = DSolve[ode, y[x], x];
implgensol = 
  gensol /.
    {HoldPattern[z_ -> InverseFunction[f_][u_]] :> 
      f[z] == u} // FullSimplify[#, C[1] > 0] &;
(* Set up equations to solve for C[1],C[2] from ICs *)
dimplsol = 
  FullSimplify[NestList[D[#, x] &, First@#, 1] /. x -> 0, 
     C[1] > 0] & /@ implgensol;
rationalized = 
  And @@@ 
   MapAt[
    Solve[#, C[1]] /. {{{C[1] -> c1_}} :> C[1] == c1, {} -> False} &,
    dimplsol, {All, 2}];
parameq = rationalized /. First@Solve[ics];
paramsol = First@Solve[Flatten@{#}, {C[1], C[2]}] & /@ parameq;
(* implicit solution *)
implsol0 = MapThread[ReplaceAll, {implgensol, paramsol}]
(*
{{2 Sqrt[2/3] (x - (Sqrt[(3 \[Pi])/2] Gamma[5/3])/(2 Gamma[7/6])) + 
    Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 2/3, 5/3, y[x]^3] y[x]^2 == 0},
 {2 Sqrt[2/3] (x + (Sqrt[(3 \[Pi])/2] Gamma[5/3])/(2 Gamma[7/6])) == 
   Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 2/3, 5/3, y[x]^3] y[x]^2}}
*)

ContourPlot[% /. y[x] -> y // Flatten // Evaluate, {x, -2, 
  2}, {y, -2.5, 1.2}]
```

[image]

`InverseFunction` really isn't that robust, hence an explicit solution leaves something to be desired (which should perhaps be expected from the plot above):

```
(* "explicit" solution *)
sol0 = MapThread[ReplaceAll, {gensol, paramsol}];
Plot[y[x] /. sol0 // Evaluate, {x, -1.01, 1.01}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, Frame ->True]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, the code still running!!

Comment: @user62716 It's rather quick for me (a couple of seconds at most).  Except `Plot`: `InverseFunction` can be slow.

Comment: Note that the maximum value of $x$ for which the solution exists is $x = \sqrt{\frac{3\pi}{2}} \frac{\Gamma(5/3)}{2 \Gamma(7/6)} \approx 1.05618...$.  If you extend the range of the `InverseFunction` plot to include this value it'll look a little better (though the curve will still end when it hits the $x$-axis, so it doesn't capture the full behavior captured in your implicit plot.)

Answer (score 4):

Note that $y^2 y'^2 + \frac23 y^3$ is a first integral of this ODE, since its derivative is proportional to the ODE itself:

```
Simplify[D[y[x]^2 y'[x]^2 + 2/3 y[x]^3, x]]

(* 2 y[x] y'[x] (y'[x]^2 + y[x] (1 + (y''[x])) *)
```

(I found this by first noting that ${y'}^2 + y y'' = \frac{d}{dx}(y y') = \frac{1}{2} \frac{d^2 (y^2)}{dx^2}$ and then making further obvious substitutions from there.)  Given the initial values $y(0) = 1$ and $y'(0) = 0$, we must have $y^2 y'^2 + \frac23 y^3 = \frac23$.  Mathematica can solve this first-order ODE, though it outputs an `InverseFunction` involving a `HyperGeometric2F1` function.  As with [@MichaelE2's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/265124/27813), the resulting plot leaves something to be desired.  Presumably the "real" solution you want for $x \in [0,1]$ would be the blue branch (which will be first function in the `DSolve` output.)

```
DSolve[{y[x]^2 y'[x]^2 + 2/3 y[x]^3 == 2/3, y[0] == 1}, y, x]
Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. %], {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh gosh, I was just about to do this... :)